# React usestate with for loop error in rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I want to create an array with random values filled in it between 0 to 7 and use this array as state value but use it in for loop of functional component call for loop multiple times when console.log state value. This will create rendering error in react

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { usestate} from "react"
export default function App() {
  const [ state , setstate ] = usestate([]);
  let arr = [] ;
  for(let i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++){
arr[i] = Math.floor((Math.random ()*8));

  }
  setstate(arr);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>State</h1>
      <p>{state}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in componentDidMount phase.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import "./style.css";
export default function App() {
  const [ state , setstate ] = useState([]);

  
  useEffect(()=>{
      let arr = [] ;
      for(let i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++){
        arr[i] = Math.floor((Math.random ()*8));
      }
      setstate(arr);
  }, [])

  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>State</h1>
      {state?.map(i=><p key={i}>{i}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `setstate(myArrayMakingFunction)` within a `useEffect` hook, this should work.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to import `useState`, instead of `usestate`.
You need to import `useEffect` as well or it will cause many re-renders.
Your solution is the code below:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./style.css";
export default function App() {
  const [ state , setstate ] = useState([]);
  let arr = [] ;
  for(let i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++){
    arr[i] = Math.floor((Math.random ()*8));

  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    setstate(arr);
  }, [])
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>State</h1>
      <p>{state}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```